# Help with gpodder / podcast-parser installation

Tags: podcast, gpodder

The latest version 3.9.2 of gpodder gives when following error when I run it:

gratis@Aurora:~$ gpodder

Error: Module "podcastparser" (python-podcastparser) not found.
         The podcastparser module can be downloaded from
         http://gpodder.org/podcastparser/

From a source checkout, you can download local copies of all
  CLI dependencies for debugging (will be placed into "src/"):

```
  python tools/localdepends.py
```

I downloaded the source code of the latest version of podcastparser 0.6. And with the little knowledge I have regarding these things I did: ./configure ->not found

make help->ran, but some error along the way

make clean -> ran

make cleandist -> also ran

but gpodder unfortunately still gives me the same error, when I try to launch it. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, the following command should solve the problem:

Under the directory podcastparser-0.6.0 run:
sudo python setup.py install

Answer (score 0):

The forum is telling me I don't have enough reputation to ask for clarification of a confusing answer. It also says that I should avoid, "asking for help, clarification or responding to other answers." Mods delete this if you want to run a closed group for people who don't need any help.

The person above wrote, "Under the directory podcastparser-0.6.0 run: sudo python setup.py install." I cannot locate that directory in my gPodder directory, or anywhere in my 14.04 Ubuntu installation. Please post the complete path.

Comment: Download the version 0.6.0 tarball from http://gpodder.org/podcastparser/.

extract it, cd to the directory and the run the command mentioned above - it worked for me.

Comment: Just worked for me as well. Thanks for the help.